# Why is my 'kMyConstant' macro redefined?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, constants

In my app delegate class I define a constant like so:

```
#define kSomeConstant    @"My_Constant_Value"
```

I then want to make use of this constant in another viewController so I defined it again exactly as above. I now get the message:

```
'kSomeConstant' macro redefined
```

Why is this the case? Is there some other way I can access the constant?

Comment: Are you importing your app delegate's header in the view controller? If you are, the macro's already defined, hence this error. You therefore don't need the extra `#define`, you can just use the constant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply redefining the constant (ie : same constant name). Choose another name, or define it just one time in a header file to access the constant value every where you import that header.

Answer (score 2):

It's likely been defined twice among the sources which are visible to the compiler. the compiler may tell you where the previous definition is if you look into the message in more detail.

To avoid this problem entirely, declare your `NSString` constants like this:

## file.h - declaration:

```
extern NSString* const kSomeConstant;
```

## file.m/mm - definition:

```
NSString* const kSomeConstant = @"My_Constant_Value";
```

Then when you need to use the constant, just `#include "file.h"`.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler has encountered two definitions of the macro.  Probably you defined it in a header file and then defined it again in a `.m` file.

If you can't figure out where the two definitions come from, try preprocessing the file with the error (in Xcode 4.2 this is under generate output in the product menu).  You can then do a search for *kSomeConstant* and that should tell you where it comes from.